# cd command not working. Cant change directory in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, cd

I was using the cd command to switch my drive to E: which basically contains all my junk files which I use for experimentation but the problem was cd was not working. The command I used was

```
cd E:  
ren *.* *.bat
```

However the time I ran this batch file (typed in notepad saved with a .bat extension) it didn't work out the cd command and ended up renaming all my desktop. When I tries using it in the command windows the result is

```
cd E:
E:\
```

then nothing what should I do.

Answer (score 21):

In order to change to a different drive you either have to add the `/D` parameter to `cd` or type the drive on a line by it's own.

```
cd /D E:\
```

Or

```
E:
```